# Why do I get an ExpectationViolationException when using a Stub?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

This test using NUnit 2.5 and Rhino.Mocks 3.5:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExcelWorksheetColumnTests
{
        private const string _name = "F1";
        private const int _index = 0;

        private MockRepository _repo;


        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp(){_repo = new MockRepository();}


        private ExcelWorksheetColumn CreateColumnUsingFixtureFieldsButWith(IExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet)
        {
            return new ExcelWorksheetColumn(_name, _index, excelWorksheet);
        }

        [Test]
        public void When_SelectedShootColumnType_Is_Changed_Raises_SelectedShootColumnTypeChanged_Event()
        {
            var stubWorksheet = _repo.Stub<IExcelWorksheet>();

            ExcelWorksheetColumn column =
                CreateColumnUsingFixtureFieldsButWith(stubWorksheet);

            stubWorksheet
               .Stub(p => p.GetSelectedShootColumnType(column))
               .Return(ShootColumnType.Generic);

            _repo.ReplayAll();

            bool itHappened = false;

            column.SelectedShootColumnTypeChanged 
                += (s, e) => { itHappened = true; };

            column.SelectedShootColumnType = ShootColumnType.SubjectId;

            Assert.That(itHappened);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            _repo.ReplayAll();
            _repo.VerifyAll();
        }
}
```

Fails with this message:

> Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException : 
>      IExcelWorksheet.SetSelectedShootColumnType(
>      ClassPhotolink.Model.CreateSubjectList.ExcelWorksheetColumn, SubjectId);
>
> Expected #0, Actual #1.

I thought Stubs were for returning values or ignoring method calls.  Why is it trying to verify a call to

```
IExcelWorksheet.SetSelectedShootColumnType(
    IExcelWorksheetColumn column, 
    ShootColumnType type)
```

?

In the rhino mocks [wiki](http://www.ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#StubExtensionMethod) it says with regards to the Stub extension method "Remember that by default **Rhino Mocks will ignore unexpected methods calls.**"

---

**Edits of Test.**

Removing the SetUp & TearDown code, this still fails:

```
    [Test]
    public void When_SelectedShootColumnType_Is_Changed_Raises_SelectedShootColumnTypeChanged_Event()
    {
        var repo = new MockRepository();
        var stubWorksheet = repo.Stub<IExcelWorksheet>();

        ExcelWorksheetColumn column = CreateColumnUsingFixtureFieldsButWith(stubWorksheet);

        stubWorksheet
            .Stub(p => p.GetSelectedShootColumnType(column))
            .Return(ShootColumnType.Generic);

        repo.ReplayAll();

        bool itHappened = false;

        column.SelectedShootColumnTypeChanged += (s, e) => { itHappened = true; };

        column.SelectedShootColumnType = ShootColumnType.SubjectId;

        Assert.That(itHappened);
    }
```

but this works as I hoped.

```
    [Test]
    public void When_SelectedShootColumnType_Is_Changed_Raises_SelectedShootColumnTypeChanged_Event()
    {
        var stubWorksheet = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IExcelWorksheet>();

        ExcelWorksheetColumn column = CreateColumnUsingFixtureFieldsButWith(stubWorksheet);

        stubWorksheet
            .Stub(p => p.GetSelectedShootColumnType(column))
            .Return(ShootColumnType.Generic);

        bool itHappened = false;

        column.SelectedShootColumnTypeChanged += (s, e) => { itHappened = true; };

        column.SelectedShootColumnType = ShootColumnType.SubjectId;

        Assert.That(itHappened);
    }
```

So it seems to have something to do with repo.Stub() versus MockRepository.GenerateStub();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Stub()` means that you **do** expect the method call. *Unexpected calls* are calls to methods on which no expectation has been set.

#### update

I'm wondering now if the problem is with your use of setup, teardown, and record/replay, which are unnecessary.

What happens if you write the test this way:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExcelWorksheetColumnTests
{
        private const string _name = "F1";
        private const int _index = 0;

        private ExcelWorksheetColumn CreateColumnUsingFixtureFieldsButWith(IExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet)
        {
            return new ExcelWorksheetColumn(_name, _index, excelWorksheet);
        }

        [Test]
        public void When_SelectedShootColumnType_Is_Changed_Raises_SelectedShootColumnTypeChanged_Event()
        {
            var stubWorksheet = MockRepository.Stub<IExcelWorksheet>();

            ExcelWorksheetColumn column =
                CreateColumnUsingFixtureFieldsButWith(stubWorksheet);

            stubWorksheet
               .Stub(p => p.GetSelectedShootColumnType(column))
               .Return(ShootColumnType.Generic);

            bool itHappened = false;

            column.SelectedShootColumnTypeChanged 
                += (s, e) => { itHappened = true; };

            column.SelectedShootColumnType = ShootColumnType.SubjectId;

            Assert.That(itHappened);
        }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I stubbed a needed return value on IExcelWorksheetColumn.GetSelectedShootColumnType(column). I didn't set an expectation on IExcelWorksheetColumn.SetSelectedShootColumnType(column,value), which is the method that it's complaining about, because it's void and I was expecting it to be ignored as an unexpected call.

Comment: Yes I get it to work like you suggested using the static GenerateStub<T>() method, thanks.  I will have to look into the differences on the various sources of confusing Rhino-Mocks documentation.